# Making an inventory remember inputs throughout game using Python

Tags: python-3.x, inventory

Im practicing my coding by remaking a game called Dope Wars using Python. If you arent familiar with Dope Wars, long story short - You travel from city to city buying and selling drugs. The goal is to make as much money as possible without being killed or arrested. Im starting out making the game to be played by command line and will code it into a GUI when Im done. The code Im posting has 2 cities available and 2 drugs to buy. The command line asks you which city you would like to go to, if you want to buy, what you want to buy, and how much. I got it to update the dictionary where I stored the values, but it doesnt save the value as you loop, and Im pretty sure it's because of using .update(), but I dont know what else to use.

So Im basically looking for a way to keep the values in the inventory so they can be added to and taken from, bought and sold. I will also need to establish a money system, random police chases, a bank, a hospital, and a gun store, any help with those aspects will help greatly as well.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import random

#  Stores dope list with prices for each city
nyDope = {'Heroin': random.randrange(1000, 2000), 'Coke': random.randrange(1000, 2000)}
laDope = {'Coke': random.randrange(1000, 2000)}

# Stores references for cities to their dope list
cityDict = {'New York': nyDope, 'Los Angeles': laDope}


# to print out dope list for NY
def ny():
    for i in nyDope:
        print(i + ': ' + str(nyDope[i]))


# To print out dope list for LA
def la():
    for i in laDope:
        print(i + ': ' + str(laDope[i]))

print('Pick your city')
city1 = input()
if city1.lower().startswith('n'):
    ny()
elif city1.lower().startswith('l'):
    la()
else:
    print('Wrong answer, now you have to go to New York')
    ny()

goAgain = True
unitsHeroin = 0
unitsCoke = 0

while goAgain == True:

    inventory = {'Heroin': int(unitsHeroin), 'Coke': int(unitsCoke)}

    print('Type what drug you want to buy:')
    buyDrugs1 = input()
    if buyDrugs1.lower() == 'heroin':
        print('How many?')
        boughtDrugs1 = input()
    elif buyDrugs1.lower() == 'coke':
        print('How many?')
        boughtDrugs1 = input()
    else:
        print("That's not an option")

    if buyDrugs1.lower() == 'heroin':
        inventory.update({'Heroin': int(unitsHeroin) + int(boughtDrugs1)})
    if buyDrugs1.lower() == 'coke':
        inventory.update({'Coke': int(unitsCoke) + int(boughtDrugs1)})

    print('Heroin: ' + str(inventory['Heroin']), '\nCoke: ' + str(inventory['Coke']))

    print('Buy more drugs? y/n')
    goAgain = input()
    if goAgain.lower().startswith('y'):
        goAgain = True
    else:
        goAgain = False
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `inventory` at the start of each iteration; move the initialization to before the main loop starts.  Or, you could make changes to the `units` variables, so that when `inventory` gets re-created, it uses their new values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code:

```
import random

#  Stores dope list with prices for each city
nyDope = {'Heroin': random.randrange(1000, 2000), 'Coke': random.randrange(1000, 2000)}
laDope = {'Coke': random.randrange(1000, 2000)}

# Stores references for cities to their dope list
cityDict = {'New York': nyDope, 'Los Angeles': laDope}


# to print out dope list for NY
def ny():
    for i in nyDope:
        print(i + ': ' + str(nyDope[i]))


# To print out dope list for LA
def la():
    for i in laDope:
        print(i + ': ' + str(laDope[i]))

print('Pick your city')
city1 = input()
if city1.lower().startswith('n'):
    ny()
elif city1.lower().startswith('l'):
    la()
else:
    print('Wrong answer, now you have to go to New York')
    ny()

goAgain = True
unitsHeroin = 0
unitsCoke = 0

inventory = {'Heroin': int(unitsHeroin), 'Coke': int(unitsCoke)}

while goAgain == True:


    print('Type what drug you want to buy:')
    buyDrugs1 = input()
    if buyDrugs1.lower() == 'heroin':
        print('How many?')
        boughtDrugs1 = input()
    elif buyDrugs1.lower() == 'coke':
        print('How many?')
        boughtDrugs1 = input()
    else:
        print("That's not an option")

    if buyDrugs1.lower() == 'heroin':
        inventory['Heroin'] = int(inventory['Heroin']) + int(boughtDrugs1)
    if buyDrugs1.lower() == 'coke':
        inventory['Coke'] = int(inventory['Coke']) + int(boughtDrugs1)

    print('Heroin: ' + str(inventory['Heroin']), '\nCoke: ' + str(inventory['Coke']))

    print('Buy more drugs? y/n')
    goAgain = input()
    if goAgain.lower().startswith('y'):
        goAgain = True
    else:
        goAgain = False
        break
```

Comment: I did this and I noticed that I can buy one drug and it saves it, buy the other drug and it saves that - saving both drugs at the same time. But then if I try to buy a duplicate drug it sets them both back to 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate drug"?

Comment: For example if I bought Coke twice in a row, or coke heroin coke.